# Equivalent of the Austrian “bedingt” and “unbedingt” in English law

Tags: germany, legal-terms, translation, austria

What is the correct English legal translation of the words *unbedingt* and *bedingt* when referring to a court sentence? E.g.:

> Jemand wurde zu vier Monaten bedingt verurteilt.
>   (Roughly: Sombeody was sentenced [bedingt] to four months.)

I read this in reference to Austrian law; I’m not sure if it’s also applicable to Germany.

Comment: I just googled it, because I never heard it before: It is only part of Autrian law (see: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedingte_Strafnachsicht) and not applicable in German law.

Comment: @Iris: Within the article you link to is a part called "Rechtslage ausserhalb Österreichs" that states that the same legal principle holds in Germany.

Comment: @Ralph M. Rickenbach, yes, in principle, but in Germany it is called "Bewährung" and written down in "§ 56 Strafaussetzung".

Comment: "bedingt" refers to a suspended sentence, that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 4):

*[Bedingte Strafnachsicht](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedingte_Strafnachsicht)* (lit. *conditional clemency*) is an Austrian legal term, often referred to as *bedingte* (ant.: *unbedingte*) Strafe.
Germans would call it *auf Bewährung* or *[ausgesetzt zur Bewährung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strafaussetzung_zur_Bew%C3%A4hrung_(Deutschland))*. Details may differ, but the principle is the same.

In legal English the whole concept is known as a *[suspended sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspended_sentence)*.

Answer (score 1):

In Austria, just as in Switzerland and Germany, a *bedingte Strafe* is a *conditional penalty*. That is a penalty that is not executed immediately, but only when within a certain period some conditions are violated. During that time, the subject is on probation (*auf Bewährung*).

*Unbedingt* therefore is translated *unconditional*.

For a definition see [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedingte_Strafnachsicht).

What differs between the countries is the severity of penalty that still can be granted as conditional.

Comment: In Germany, _bedingte Strafe_ wouldn’t be used (and probably not understood either). Instead, you would speak of a _Bewährungsstrafe_ or say that _die Strafe wurde zur Bewährung ausgesetzt_. – Legal terms are probably the domain where the varieties of German differ most.

Comment: I understand the legal term is _suspended sentence_. (Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspended_sentence)

Answer (score -1):

*bedingt* is derived from *Bedingung*. In dict.cc (if you have searched) you could have found the *Law*-tag with the translation

> conditionally